# Installing django with easy_install in a virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, easy-install

I'm new to virtualenv, so perhaps I'm simply overlooking something. I have successfully set up a virtual environment. I have run `activate.bat`, which is evident in the command window and when I check `PATH` environment variable.

I'm running 64-bit Python 2.7.8 on Windows in my virtual environment. Following the activation of the virtualenv, I execute `easy_install django`, which installs django, but installs it globally and not to the isolated environment. I confirmed this by firing up the interpreter and typing `import django`...resulting in an import error.

Without skipping a beat, I tried `pip install django` from the same activated command prompt, and it worked like a charm.

So...with `easy_install`...what gives? Is this an `easy_install` error or a `virtualenv` error? Unfortunately, since the django install via `easy_install` didn't fail to install (it installed globally), I have no helpful error messages to provide.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. The correct tool to use is pip, easy_install predates virtualenv and is not really aware of it.

Comment: Well, then why include it in the virtualenv install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never use the `activate.bat` script. I just end up with problems if I do (edit - after looking into it a little, I suspect it is a legacy script for people using old MS-DOS prompts). Use the `activate.ps1` script.

`...\virtualenv_name\Scripts\activate.ps1`

You may have to change permissions (see [the execution policy section](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide.html) in the guide). As I understand it, the `RemoteSigned` policy is preferred over `Unrestricted`.

You should get a prefix on your command prompt with the name of your virtualenv. Something like `(virtualenv_name) PC C:\>` Now pip should work:

`pip install django`

You can use `easy_install` but ... don't since pip is the standard. Unless you have a special case where it works and `pip` doesn't.

Comment: I suppose that is the way of it ;)

Comment: I had to set my execution policy to `Unrestricted` to get this to work, which is unfortunate. And get this, executing `easy_install django` from within the powershell activated virtualenv worked. Would love to figure out why the difference, but I need to  get back to work...

Comment: One more comment about this method...I had to run `.\activate` from the `Scripts` directory to switch to the virtualenv, but subsequently had to run `deactivate` (minus the dot and trailing backslash) to deactivate it. In other words, this works `.\activate`, this doesn't `activate` while this works `deactivate`, this doesn't `.\deactivate`. I can pretty well guess why the difference here, just seems a little counter intuitive...

Comment: @ionalchemist It's a limitation / design feature of powershell. What I do is 1) rename `activate.ps1` to `activate_some_identifier.ps1`  2) add each `virtualenv\Scripts` directory to my path and then 3) start typing `activa` followed by tab-tab-tab until it finds the activate that I want. Also, if this works for you (I guess others will run into the batch file problem), could you please mark it as solved?

Comment: While I appreciate your answer and our discussion, it does not answer my question, which was about `easy_install` and why it failed. That's what I'm after...thanks

Comment: @ionalchemist Did you retry `easy_install` after using `activate.ps1`? As I mentioned in the answer, `easy_install` should work after activation with the ps1 script. I just tried it (py 2.7 with easy_install after activation) and it installed into my virtualenv.

Comment: Come to think of it, I did!

Comment: @ionalchemist I just saw your previous comments. Not sure how I missed them before. You probably shouldn't set it to Unrestricted - I think most people use `RemoteSigned` to allow local stuff only. As you found and mentioned in my answer, `easy_install` does work fine after proper activation. You really want to know ~why~ it doesn't work after using the batch? Let's see.. if we can trust [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-virtualenv/tPEFPpGMAeE), the reason is that the batch file runs in a separate process from the activate shell.

Comment: @ionalchemist If I use `pip install django` or `easy_install django` after the batch file, I get this wacky error `Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'` So I got less success than you did. My tentative conclusion is that the batch file is not compatible with powershell. Maybe it is there for old plain dos prompts? I couldn't find any documentation on it.